# How to write a code in python that is a recursive function that returns a string with each character in its argument repeated?

Tags: python, recursion

For example the word 'what' would be wwhhaatt.
I'm having trouble figuring how to do this recursively.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion generally consists of two things:

- Defining a complicated case in terms of a slightly less complicated case; and
- Defining a base case on which all other cases eventually rest.

In your particular case, given a string, the following pseudo-code should do what you want:

```
def dubble(s):
    if s is "":
        return ""
    return s.firstChar + s.firstChar + dubble(s.otherChars)
```

In other words, to double up a string: if the string is empty, return the empty string. Otherwise make two copies of the first character and append that to the doubled-up rest of the string. Given the string `'what'`, you'll see:

```
dubble('what')
    -> 'w' + 'w' + dubble('hat')
    -> 'w' + 'w' + 'h' + 'h' + dubble('at')
    -> 'w' + 'w' + 'h' + 'h' + 'a' + 'a' + dubble('t')
    -> 'w' + 'w' + 'h' + 'h' + 'a' + 'a' + 't' + 't' + dubble('')
    -> 'w' + 'w' + 'h' + 'h' + 'a' + 'a' + 't' + 't'
    -> 'wwhhaatt'
```

Now, though that pseudo-code above *looks* a bit like Python, that's only because Python is a brilliant language for doing pseudo-code. You'll still have to implement the algorithm into "real" Python, keeping in mind the first character of a string `s` can be obtained with `s[0]` and the other characters with `s[1:]`.

If this is classwork or even self-education, I urge you to do that on your own. If not, and you just want a solution, you can see one below<sup>1</sup>.

Of course, Python aficionados (who seem to value brevity) will simply bypass the recursion altogether, and do:

```
print(''.join([c * 2 for c in "what"]))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> One solution if it's not meant to be educational and you just want an answer:

```
def dubble(s):
    if len(s) == 0: return ""
    return s[0] + s[0] + dubble(s[1:])

print(dubble("what"))                  # Remove outer () for Python 2
```

Comment: I wrote out a solution just for kicks... and my solution is almost exactly the same.  Those two rules often lead to similar solutions when it comes to recursion. +1